# list running services inside an Alpine Container

Tags: service, containers, alpine-linux

I am working with an Alpine container and I would like to list all running services inside this container (something like `service --status-all`). The container is based on the [Mosquitto-Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto/) from Dockerhub.

With a little search, I have found that the `openrc` package must be installed. I tried to install it using apk

```
apk add openrc
```

then it returns:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
140449180932936:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
140449180932936:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community: No such file or directory
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  openrc (no such package):
    required by: world[openrc]
```

could anyone help?! Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: A container is not running multiple processes, it is only running one. In this case [`/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/docker/2.0/Dockerfile#L105)